# Change modified date for files in dropbox

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to change the modified date for files in Dropbox when viewed in the web viewer like the image below ?

[image: dropbox web view screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The "modified date/time" reported seems to be the actual file modified time for me, not the time it was uploaded.

HOWEVER, the date/time that Dropbox reports also takes into account the timezone you have set on your account, which is actually a bit confusing if you experience changes in Daylight Saving Time (or have an incorrect timezone set)!

> Is there a way to change the modified date for files in Dropbox when viewed in the web viewer

Only by going into "Settings" and changing your timezone. It should default to "Automatically detect timezone", but if you deselect that you can pick from a list.